# How can I split an array by delimiters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing

For example, if I have an array like this:

```rb
[:open, 1, :open, 2, 3, :close, 4, :close, :open, 5, :close]
```

I want to get this:

```rb
[[1, [2, 3], 4], [5]]
```

The `:open` effectively becomes `[` and `:close` becomes `]`

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could probably do this with a stack, but it's pretty easy to design recursively:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

x = [:open, 1, :open, 2, 3, :close, 4, :close, :open, 5, :close]

def parse(list)
  result = []
  while list.any?
    case (item = list.shift)
    when :open
      result.push(parse(list))
    when :close
      return result
    else
      result.push(item)
    end
  end

  return result
end

puts parse(x).inspect
```

Note that this will destroy your original array.  You should `clone` it before passing it in if you want to preserve it.

Comment: I didn't know that you can use `any?` as negation of `empty?`. That's cool.

Comment: After seeing this, I was replacing all my `not x.empty?`, `!x.empty?`, `unless x.empty?` into `x.any?` or `if x.any?`, but then I realized that I have to be careful not to do this to String as it is not defined for String.

Comment: By using recursion you *are* using an (implicit) stack `:)`

Answer (score 4):

```
ar = [:open, 1, :open, 2, 3, :close, 4, :close, :open, 5, :close]
p eval(ar.inspect.gsub!(':open,', '[').gsub!(', :close', ']'))
#=> [[1, [2, 3], 4], [5]]
```

Comment: I could suggest to use `/,\s+:close/`. And in ruby 1.9 you can use `to_s` instead of `inspect`

Comment: This is a lot less generic because it only works well for arrays of literals. Also, you don't need to replace the `,` before `:close`: `.gsub!(':close', ']')` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The same to steenslag, but a little cleaner

```
a = [:open, 1, :open, 2, 3, :close, 4, :close, :open, 5, :close]
eval(a.to_s.gsub(':open,','[').gsub(', :close',']'))
#=> [[1, [2, 3], 4], [5]]
```